# Django игнорирует settings.py, лежащий в проекте и вместо него использует свой global_settings.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pycharm

Весь вопрос в заголовке. Использую PyCharm и настройки берутся из `global_settings.py`, хотя я ожидаю, что они должны браться из `settings.py` в папке проекта. Может что-то куда-то надо прописать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в проекте есть файл -  manage.py. В нем есть строка:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<projectname>.settings")
```

вот этот вот settings в конце и есть имя файла настроек.

Comment: Строчка такая есть и <myprojectname>.settings присутствует, но вот всё равно этот файл настроек не используется, а берется исключительно global_settings.py

Comment: Так, давайте по порядку.

Версия Django
Как вы создавали проект?
Как вы запускаете проект
Откуда вообще взялся файл global_settings.py, сама джанга его не создает

Comment: Весия django: 1.6
Проект создавал через PyCharm (file -> new project)
Проект пробовал запускать двумя способами:
1. через кнопку в IDE
2. и через команду python manage.py runserver (еще пробовал указать 127.0.0.1:8000, но результат тот же)
Файл global_settings.py лежит в C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\django\conf (у меня венда, поэтому путь такой) и собственно global_settings.py это файл-шаблон, значения которого надо переопределять в myprojectname/settings.ру но так как у меня этот файл полностью игнорируется, то все данные берутся только из global_settings.py

Comment: > Почему вы решили что Django не использует ваш settings.py, какие настройки не применились?
Определяю по этой ошибке: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

в settings.py SECRET_KEY заполнен,
а в global_settings.py нет

Comment: Какова у вас структура проекта?
Должно быть так:

    projectname
      projectname
        settings.py
      manage.py

settings.py лежит не рядом с manage.py а выше?
manage.py runserver вы выполняете находясь в папке проекта?

Comment: Вы меняли или копировали settings.py после того как его автоматически создал PyCharm?
Если да, то покажите содержимое

Comment: Структура точно такая, как в вашем примере. 
settings.py не лежит рядом с manage.py

Comment: Вы не поверите, но всё заработало. Только что. Само) Проблема была со вчерашнего дня. Не понимаю я магию windows, лучше вернусь обратно в линукс. @LinnTroll, дам вам лучший ответ за терпеливые попытки помочь